# terraform - donot create ec2 instance if it already exists

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

So i came across a scenario in terraform, where the requirement was check if a resource(lets say ec2) already exists in AWS and if it exits then do not create it.
Now i understand that if the ec2 "foobar" was created for the first time using terraform and then if we try to create it again, then terraform apply will say that no new changes were made to the infra. But what if resource 'foobar` is already created manually or via any other tool, how does terraform handle the scenario in that case.

I understand that `data` block in terraform is used to retrieve the existing information and i tried to write something like this

```
data "aws_instance" "foobar"{
    filter {
        tags   = "name"
        values = ["foobar"]
  }
    most_recent = true
}
```

But this does not work, what would be a better way to handle this scenario

Comment: It doesn't handle it because it knows nothing about resources created outside of it. Terraform keeps all the resource it created in the state file. If something gets created manually, terraform has no way of knowing about that. That is, unless you import that resource into state or if you take care about the naming convention.

Comment: i was asked this question, and when i answered that we need to import the resources, that answer was not accepted :(

Comment: Well, make sure the names are random enough so the overlap doesn't happen.

Answer (score 1):

Since Terraform is a desired-state system, the statement "create this if it doesn't already exist" is not meaningful: it is an imperative command, rather than a desired state.

Unfortunately, if you rephrase that into a declarative statement then you end up with a contradiction: "if the object exists then it doesn't exist". If you *were* able to express that statement to Terraform then you'd end up with a configuration that can never converge, because after your initial `terraform apply` the object would then exist and so your configuration would declare that it should not exist, and thus Terraform would plan to destroy it.

Instead, you must decide explicitly whether a particular Terraform configuration is either *managing* a particular object (a `resource` block) or *depending on* that object (a `data` block). There is no way to make that decision dynamically, because then it would be ambiguous whether a particular Terraform configuration is managing that object. For example, it would be unclear whether `terraform destroy` should destroy the object.

If you have an existing object that was created outside of Terraform but you now want to use Terraform to manage it *moving forward*, then Terraform calls that concept "importing": it takes an existing object and associates it with one of the `resource` blocks in your configuration. If you run [`terraform import`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/import) to create such an association, then Terraform will behave as if it had been the one to create that object originally, despite that not being true.